# Data attribute not rendering in the desired format when added dynamically ,not escaping double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add a div tag dynamically with some data attributes but the data attributes are not rendering in the right format.Please find the code below

```
$('<a href="#" id="opendialog2" data-role="button">Open Dialog2</a><div id="inlinecontent2" style="display:none" data-options="{"mode":"blank","headerText":"Yo","headerClose":true,"blankContent":true}"><ul data-role="listview"><li>Some</li><li>List</li><li>Items</li></ul><a rel="close" data-role="button" href="#">Close</a></div>').appendTo('#myDiv')
```

The div inlinecontent2 is rendered as

```
<div mode":"blank","headertext":"yo","headerclose":true,"blankcontent":true}"="" data-options="{" style="display: none;" id="inlinecontent2">
```

The data options attributes renders all messed up

Im wish to get it rendered like below

```
<div id="inlinecontent" style="display:none" data-options='{"mode":"blank","headerText":"Yo","headerClose":true,"blankContent":true}'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes (differently):

```
$('<a href="#" id="opendialog2" data-role="button">Open Dialog2</a><div id="inlinecontent2" style="display:none" data-options=\'{"mode":"blank","headerText":"Yo","headerClose":true,"blankContent":true}\'><ul data-role="listview"><li>Some</li><li>List</li><li>Items</li></ul><a rel="close" data-role="button" href="#">Close</a></div>').appendTo('#myDiv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
$('<a href="#" id="opendialog2" data-role="button">Open Dialog2</a><div id="inlinecontent2" style="display:none" data-options="{\"mode\":\"blank\",\"headerText\":\"Yo\",\"headerClose\":true,\"blankContent\":true}"><ul data-role="listview"><li>Some</li><li>List</li><li>Items</li></ul><a rel="close" data-role="button" href="#">Close</a></div>').appendTo('#myDiv')
```